# Why did Indra marry Shachi, the daughter of an Asura?

Tags: indra, asuras

Shachi is daughter of an Asura Puloma, and is thus an Asuri. Shakra fights always with the Asuras, yet He married Shachi. And Shachi is now become a Goddess. Why did Maghavat marry daughter of an Asura Puloma.

Comment: what do you feel is wrong in it ?

Comment: @RakeshJoshi Because Indra always fights with Asuras. Then why

Comment: Even some gods are referred to as asuras. But in puranic literature some are synonymous to demons. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asura Even Ravana father was rishi but mother was rakshasa .

Comment: All asuras are not bad. Have you forgot name of asuras who was famous coz of their good deeds? Some names are Bhakt Prahlad, King Bali (grandson of Prahlad), Vibhishan and so on.... If many asuras did wrong then we can't judge all asuras on behalf of one sided mentality. Even Gods did many asura's vrities karma. Even King of God did many grave sins which was no less then asura's deeds. So all Asuras are not bad and all Gods are not always good. Only Lords remains pure all the time.

Comment: @Rishabh Exactly What you said is the point. Asuras is only a Yoni, and Deva is also a Yoni. So we, cannot call Asuras bad just because they are Asuras, and Devas as Good just because they are in Deva Yoni. Bad and Good should be decided basis to Karma.

Comment: What is 'Shakra'?

Comment: @Yogi Indra's Name. Shakra

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Interesting question and a valid one. Why should Indra, the ruler of Devas marry an Asura princess? There is no clear cut answer but the Rigved contains one particular hymn that is spoken by **Shachi** herself and which gives an insight into what could have happened.

In **[Verse 159, Book 10 of Rigved](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv10159.htm)** Shachi states that there was some competition for Indra's affections and she beat many **rivals** to become his queen and even Indra was submissive to her after that:

[image]
[image]

> 1. YON Sun hath mounted up, and this my happy fate hate mounted high.
>      **I knowing this, as conqueror have won my husband for mine own.**
> 2. I am the banner and the head, a mighty arbitress am I:
>      **I am victorious, and my Lord shall be submissive to my will.**
> 3. My Sons are slayers of the foe, my Daughter is a ruling Queen:
>      **I am victorious: o’er my Lord my song of triumph is supreme.**
> 4. Oblation, that which Indra gave and thus grew glorious and most high,—
>      This have I offered, O ye Gods, and **rid me of each rival wife.**
> 5. **Destroyer of the rival wife, Sole Spouse, victorious, conqueror,**
>      The others' glory have I seized as ’twere the wealth of weaker Dames.
> 6. **I have subdued as conqueror these rivals, these my fellow-wives,**
>      That I may hold imperial sway over this Hero and the folk.

It appears to be sort of a Swayamvar of the opposite kind where many women were vying for Indra's affections but Shachi beat them to become his chief queen. The book **[A Classical Dictionary of Hindu Mythology and Religion, Geography, History](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=leH7AQAAQBAJ&pg=PA125&lpg=PA125&dq=Taittiriya%20Brahmana%20indrani&source=bl&ots=CWVhryg0IT&sig=h3nqj9wqe2QftMT-YVRk1My_mkc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjLuoPrqbHWAhXBLY8KHbPQBc0Q6AEIJTAA#v=onepage&q=indrani&f=false)** also refers to the Taittirya Brahman stating that Shachi won because she was the most beautiful of all other godesses:

[image]

Comment: It is A Nice answer. So basically Pulomajaa won Vaasava as her husband in a SvayamVara. Well, of course, Indra did nothing wrong. After all, being Asura is not synonym of Being Bad.

Comment: Thanks @AnuragSingh yeah I guess we discussed Asuras in the Vritra question :)

Comment: Haha. Yes. But was needed here too, so that reader may not harbour bad feelings towards Asuras. :)